# Can I change iPhone Mail app to show archive button on detail screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app

When I go into the detail screen of an email in the Mail app on my iPhone the center button at the bottom is move to trash. Can I change that to archive instead? I realize I can long press on that button and then choose archive but I'd prefer a single press for archive as I use it much more than delete.

I also realize I can swipe to archive from my inbox list but frequently I'd like to archive only after reading the full email.